# Grouping SNPs as locus based on defined distance

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a sorted file of IDs and numbers (positions). I need to group the positions in the 2nd column into intervals of 500 and then split into different files.

Input

```
snp00001    200
snp00002    300
snp00003    400
snp00004    500
snp00005    600
snp00006    900
snp00007    1500
snp00008    1800
snp00009    3000
snp00010    3500
snp00011    4000
snp00012    5000
```

Desired output

```
snp00001    200 Group1
snp00002    300 Group1
snp00003    400 Group1
snp00004    500 Group1
snp00005    600 Group1
snp00006    900 Group2
snp00007    1500    Group3
snp00008    1800    Group3
snp00009    3000    Group4
snp00010    3500    Group4
snp00011    4000    Group5
snp00012    5000    Group6
```

These groups are then saved to different files, renamed as `Group1`, `Group2`, `Group3` and `Group4`, respectively.

I've tried `bedtools` and some other commands, but the problem can't be solved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So your final output file, for example `group1`, will have lines like `snp00001    200 Group1`? Or do you just want the SNP ID and position without the group name in the final output?

Comment: Hi @terdon, thank you for your reply. Yes, I would appreciate if the group names are included in the output too.

Comment: OK, done. By the way, make sure to clarify if you are working with a 1-based or 0-based system. Both are in common use and it can be _very_ confusing to figure out which is right for each format. Bed is 0-based for example and GFF is 1-based. This is a great post on the subject: [Tutorial:Cheat Sheet For One-Based Vs Zero-Based Coordinate Systems](https://www.biostars.org/p/84686/). Also, you might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: Thanks @terdon. Works like a charm!

Comment: Are you sure? In your desired output, you have `snp00009    3000` in  Group4 and not in Group5. Is that wrong? I deleted my answer since I was placing 3000 in Group5. Where do you actually want it?

Comment: Hi @terdon, oops sorry my bad, just checked the files and snp00009 should be in Group 4, so does snp00010 in Group 5. For snp snp00001 to snp00005, they are in the first 500 intervals, so they are okay. Next snp will be snp00006, after adding 500 interval (900+500), snp00007 (1500) is not in the range and therefore they are not grouped together. Coming up is snp00007, adding 500 interval, snp00008 is in the range and therefore they are grouped together. The 500 intervals are counted from the first snp. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135468/discussion-between-terdon-and-austin7923).

Comment: You have `snp00009    3000    Group4` and `snp00010    3500    Group4` but shouldn't group4 stop at 3499 if it started at 3000 and had a range of 500 as THAT would be 500 numbers? If not then which group would a line with `700` fall into - group1 (`200-700`) or group 2 which would then presumably be `700-1400`? It's also not clear if your groups should start with `200-699` then `800-1299`, or `200-699` then `900-1399` or something else as the numbers in your example dont test the limits of the ranges and so leave the requirements ambiguous and not adequate to test a potential solution against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect job for `awk`:

```
$ awk -v step=500 -v OFS='\t' \
'{ 
    if(NR==1 || $2>limit){
        limit=$2+step
        group++
    } 
    file="Group"group; print $0,file 
}' input_file 
snp00001    200 Group1
snp00002    300 Group1
snp00003    400 Group1
snp00004    500 Group1
snp00005    600 Group1
snp00006    900 Group2
snp00007    1500    Group3
snp00008    1800    Group3
snp00009    3000    Group4
snp00010    3500    Group4
snp00011    4000    Group5
snp00012    5000    Group6
```

To print into separate files, do:

```
awk -v step=500 -v OFS='\t' \
'{ 
    if(NR==1 || $2>limit){
        limit=$2+step
        group++
    } 
    file="Group"group; print $0,file > file
}' input_file
```

This will produce files `Group1` through `Group5` from your example data, with this format:

```
$ cat Group1 
snp00001    200 Group1
snp00002    300 Group1
snp00003    400 Group1
snp00004    500 Group1
snp00005    600 Group1

$ cat Group6
snp00012    5000    Group6
```

Comment: Hi @terdon, snp00005 and snp00006 should not be grouped together. After the 500 intervals from snp00001, from snp00005 another 500 intervals are calculated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, @austin7923, I think I figured it out, answer updated. You might want to edit your question and clarify that you want to start counting the intervals from the first number found, that wasn't clear.

Comment: Hi @terdon, so sorry about my misleading question. Thank you for solving this!

Comment: You should move `file="Group"group` into the `if` part where group is incremented for efficiency. You should also close() the previous file in the `if` part for efficiency and portability to all awks otherwise you could hit a "too many open files" error.

Comment: I'm not sure `limit=$2+step` is correct but the example in the question doesn't test the ranges and has apparently wrong values so idk...

Comment: @EdMorton yeah, we hashed it out in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135468/discussion-between-terdon-and-austin7923

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl + csplit. The range operator or the flip-flop operator "..."

```bsh
perl \
  -lMconstant='LIM,500' \
  -sane \
'
  my $e = do{$a=$F[1];1;} ... $F[1]-$a>LIM;

  print(qq($_\tGroup$k)),next
    if $e !~ /E0/ || $eof;

  print(q());$k++;

  redo if !eof || !$eof++;

' -- -k=1 file |
csplit --suppress-matched \
  -sz -f 'Group' - '/^$/' '{*}'
```

---